Error binding socket when starting YugabyteDB
I have a problem when using yugabyte with persistence volume in docker.
On first run everything work fine, but when re-create container with existing volume, it fail to start:
master.err :
./../src/yb/master/master_main.cc:131] Network error (yb/util/net/socket.cc:325): Error binding socket to 172.28.0.3:7100: Cannot assign requested address (system error 99)
    @       0x2938618  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @       0x29394d3  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @       0x29399cf  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @       0x2677cde  main
    @   0x7fb112f46825  __libc_start_main
    @       0x260802e  _start 


OS/linux error 99 is:
#define    EADDRNOTAVAIL    99    /* Cannot assign requested address */

It means that from the perspective of the process, the network address (12.28.0.3) does not exist, and thus it cannot bind to it.
